# Get connectionId outside of Hub, SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

How do I get the clients connectionId/clientId outside of the Hub?.. I have managed to do the following:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
```

But in that context-object there is no such thing as a `clientId`.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement IConnected/IDisconnect on the Hub and manually keep track of clients for example in a database, then pull back the list when required.  The example below is from the [SignalR Wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs)

```
public class Status : Hub, IDisconnect, IConnected
{
    public Task Disconnect()
    {
        return Clients.leave(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public Task Connect()
    {
        return Clients.joined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public Task Reconnect(IEnumerable<string> groups)
    {
        return Clients.rejoined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Even we save the id, how do we know which id is current connection id outside of hub? only the time can't be correct if there are so many connections.

Answer (score 4):

Why would there be a connection Id on the global context? Which connection would it be in reference to? When you get the global context, you are accessing a one way channel from server to client and can send messages over it. You don't have access to the connection id of the hub since you aren't calling into it. You can store them somewhere in your application if you need to use them.

Comment: Not everyone builds chat servers. I think implied was how to get the ConnectionId used by the current client so a message could be sent to just that user/session. I'm wondering myself how to best do this in an MVC Action from a client where I want to send progress messages. There are some techniques for caching ConnectionIds by the username but I have not seen anything decent for allowing for the same user having multiple connections which is often the case with web apps. Ideas for that? Thanks.

Comment: You send it from the client to your mvc action. It's available on the client via $.connection.hub.id.

Answer (score 1):

I changed @davidfowl comment into an answer - You send it from the client to your mvc action. It's available on the client via $.connection.hub.id

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { console.log($.connection.hub.id); });
```

And then do what ever you want with it then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Solution.
You can invoke a method inside the `hub` and you can return the `connection ID` from there.

**In Controller**

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
MyHub _connectedHub= new MyHub();
var connectedUserID = _connectedHub.GetConnectionID();
```

**In Hub**

```
public string GetConnectionID()
{
     return "Your Connection ID as String"  //This can be stored in a list or retrieved in any other method
}
```

You'll get required ID outside the hub in `connectedUserID` Variable.
Hope This Helps.